# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/JspFactory

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to deploy a web app on Tomcat and I have done all I could to make the dependencies correct to make it work but Tomcat keeps giving me Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.jsp.JspFactory

Technologies stack : Tomcat 10.1.6,
Jarkarta EE,
Java 17,
Eclipse

```
         <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
         <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
         <version>10.0.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
         <dependency>
         <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>6.0.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>       
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
         <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.1</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
     <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

I have further attached jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-3.0.1.jar
jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-3.0.0.jar at the lib at WEB-INF folder.

Hope someone can advise me how to resolve the error to make Tomcat start. Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your suffering around the tomcat/jsp dependencies.

As far as I can tell you are missing the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have found it quicker/easier, while trying to sort these TOMCAT dependencies out, to simply drop the jars into %TOMCAT_HOME%/lib and then finally when it works, go back and tidy up. The jar is [downloadable](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/jakarta.servlet.jsp/jakarta.servlet.jsp-api/3.1.1) here.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer.?

Comment: How do I accept it ? I have already put a arrow up

Comment: Accept it like this - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow/86979#86979

Comment: I checked, ticked already.